# mount multiple hard drives to one folder as one drive

Tags: command-line, mount

I'm pretty new to this and have been searching for this a while now..

I need to be able to mount multiple hard drives as "one drive" at /mydata folder. How do i do this as easy as possible in command-line? I need to be able to addd more drives later on if needed.. ;)

Edit: I use Ubuntu 14.04 server testing with vmware atm..

-S

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. We need some more info. First, what OS are you using? Second, how are these drives set up? Are they part of a LVM? If not, that's probably what you're looking for unless mounting each partition as `/mydata/A`, `/mydata/B` etc is OK.

Answer (score 0):

@Ståle Gulbrandsen you can use raid concept. Raid  is a data storage virtualization technology that combines multiple disk drive components into a logical unit for the purposes of data redundancy or performance improvement.I Hope that raid will do your needful

Comment: Can you provide instructions on how to do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: I will post how i did it if i manage to do it.. 

Answer (score 0):

LVM2 is made for this.

sudo apt-get install lvm2

Mark partitions as type 8e linux lvm

Create pv's (physical volumes) on as many physical partitions as you desire.

Add the pv's to a volume group

Create a logical volume on the volume group

Create a file system on the logical volume.

When you add more disk, create the pv's, then extend the vg, lv and file system.